# How do I access the table wrapped by one Azure Mobile Services TableController from another TableController?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a new .Net back end Azure Mobile Service project with two TableController classes wrapping a table each and and I want to access one table from the other Controller. Am I supposed to instantiate one Controller from the other or just use the context object directly to access the data?

e.g.

RegistrationItemController wraps the RegistrationItem table

```
public class RegistrationItemController : TableController<RegistrationItem>
```

and UserController wraps the User table

```
public class UserController : TableController<User>
```

In my PostUser method on UserController am I supposed to instantiate an instance of RegistrationItemController and access it along the lines of:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUser(User item)
    {
        //look up RegistrationItem to validate this request
        RegistrationItemController registrationController = new RegistrationItemController();

        var registrationItem = registrationController.GetRegistrationItem(item.RegistrationId);

        ...
```

I say along the lines of as the above won't work as I can't call the protected Initialize method of RegistrationItemController which creates the context and creates the DomainManager.

Or am I going about this the wrong way and UserController should just its own context to access the RegistrationItem data directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same question. Apparently there is no way of accessing on TableController from the another one but there is a simple way of querying. In the **Initialize** method of each **TableController** an Entity Framework **DbContext** is created which can be saved as a member variable and then be used for querying every table exposed by the Entity Framework Context defined in your code.